# Power BI - If Indicator equals 1 then set Result column that matches Group to 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three columns, as shown below.  I am struggling with getting the results I want.  Basically, I have a column (**Indicator**) that is either 1 or 0, then a **Group** column, and the **Result** column is where my calculation is.  What I want my calculation to do is return 1 for any matching **Group** if an **Indicator** is 1.

I've tried endless combinations of IF, GROUPBY, FILTER, SUMX, MAXX, etc, and cannot get a result.  The most common thing I get is the Error "The expression refers to multiple columns.  Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Any help or advice on this is appreciated, I'm open to other ways to get this.  Please let me know if I can provide more detail.

| Indicator | Group | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 0 | B | 0 |
| 0 | B | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following

```
Column =
CALCULATE (
    MAXX (
        GROUPBY (
            source,
            source[Group],
            "max", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP (), source[Indicator] )
        ),
        [max]
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( source, source[Group] )
)
```

[image: Calculated Column]

If you prefer a measure, you can use the same for `measure` also and it will return the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked for my needs, I appreciate the help!